# Send data via AX.25 using GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio

Is there a library or link that can let me send data (e.g. text) using AX.25 with GNURadio 3.8 similar to gr-packetradio? The problem with gr-packetradio is that it is not compatible with GNURadio 3.8.

```
Please help.
```

Regards,
Bryan